# When to use a module and when to use a global scope

Tags: ruby, module

This is a simple question: Should I have a module that contains all my classes (and submodules):

```
module ProjectName

  class Something
    # code
  end

  module Abc
    # code
  end

end
```

Or simply everything in a global scope:

```
class Something
  # code
end

module Abc
  # code
end
```

Comment: what is the subject of your concern?

Comment: I don't know whether I should have a global module I put all classes of my project into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is considered good practice not to pollute your global scope. Namespacing your application into modules, encapsulating related behaviour makes it easier to comprehend, helps avoid naming conflicts, and lets you easily port parts of your code into other applications or contexts.

In Ruby it also gives you a natural way of storing module wide constants, and gives you the option to add methods that don't need a containing object directly to the module.

In some languages, (notably JavaScript) scoping also has an impact on performance, as keeping objects in the global scope might prevent them from getting qualified for garbage collection.